# What Do I Need To Do To Enable My EC2 Windows Instance As a Web Server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012

I'm not a hardware guys, so I'm probably missing something simple, but I did the following:

1. Created a Windows VM.
2. Activated the web server role/IIS features (I can successfully serve a page via localhost when remote desktopped in).
3. Made sure outgoing port 80 wasn't blocked in Windows firewall.
4. Created a load balancer that pointed to the instance (to make enablement of SSL easier).

I then tried pulling up both the load balancer public DNS and the VM'w and neither of them pull up any web page. The Windows VM instance reports that it's running, but the load balancer reports that the VM is OutOfService trying to forward port 80.

What do I need to do to be able to serve my web site?

Comment: Open port 80 on the AWS security group assigned to your EC2 instance.

Comment: That was it. Want to put it in the form of an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open port 80 on the AWS security group assigned to your EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Open inbound access to port RDP in your security group.

This will make you to access the Windows server of your ec2-instance.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the Security Group assigned to your EC2 instance and add a rule to allow port 80 in Inbound and outbount rules.